# Use bind_param on the database name instead of just values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to bind a variable to my PHP prepared statement. However, I'm trying to apply it to the database name, not a value. This is what I have, which works:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$con = mysqli_connect(connection_values);
$query = "INSERT INTO example (field) VALUES ?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $foo);
$stmt->execute();
```

What I'm trying to do is something similar to this:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';
$con = mysqli_connect(connection_values);
$query = "INSERT INTO example_? (field) VALUES ?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $bar, $foo);
$stmt->execute();
```

This would insert `foo` into the table `example_bar`. However, trying this errors with

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt
>
> mysqli_stmt::execute(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

Is this possible?

Comment: FYI: You cannot bind column/table names

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: Way around which? Binding table names?

Comment: Well, why can't I bind column/table names?

Comment: You'll have to ask the folks who wrote the `mysqli_` set of functions. Can't you just sanitize the table name if you are worried about it?

Comment: perhaps making use of sprintf() to do what you want. $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO example_%s (field) VALUES ?;", 'table'); As well you need to bind each value seperately, so you need to do VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), not VALUES ?